# Strech background inside div and let to be scrollable

Tags: image, css, twitter-bootstrap, background

I have a landing page which should hold a stretched background image on page load and the bottom content should not be visible to user just when scrolls down and content should not have as background the image. Here is what I [try](http://jsfiddle.net/lgtsfiddler/J6bYR/1/)

but in this case the image doesn't scroll

**Markup**

```
<div class="home">
    <img src="/wp-content/themes/clothes/assets/img/bg.png" class="bg">
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
img.bg {
  /* Set rules to fill background */
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 1024px;

  /* Set up proportionate scaling */
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;

  /* Set up positioning */
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) { /* Specific to this particular image */
  img.bg {
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -512px;   /* 50% */
  }
}
```

Comment: Since you're using bootstrap have you considered using ScrollSpy? http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy

Answer (score 0):

In short, the image isn't scrolling because using `position:fixed;` or `position:absolute;` will remove the element from the document flow and will no longer interact with the elements on the page in the way you may expect.

If you remove that it will scroll. I'm sorry but I'm having trouble understanding where the content should be in relation to the image. Can you please clarify so I can help you with the rest of your question?

Comment: thank you for your feedback. The content should come after the image in the bottom